# How to redirect parent page after some seconds when user clicks on image?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to redirect the parent page once user has clicked image on the parent page and redirected to child page in new tab and later after 5 seconds parent page redirects to xyz page.Please help how it will happen?

```
<a href="karloshopflipkart.php?param=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>" id="flip" target
='_blank'></a>

<!-- cHild page to which page redirected on clicking image -->

<?php
session_start();
 require_once("navig.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))  {?>
<?php
    require_once('connect.php');
    $dbb = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
        $para=$_SESSION['user_id'];
         if(isset($_GET['param'])){
        $coola=$_GET['param'];
$querye = "INSERT INTO orderdata(user_id, store_used) ".
                        "VALUES ('$coola', 'Flipkart')";
mysqli_query ($dbb, $querye);                       
mysqli_close($dbb);     
}   
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href="http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/?affid=caretechc&affExtParam1=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>"; // the redirect goes here
},5000);
</script>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container2">

<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
<style>
```

Comment: You'd have to try to open a new browser window by means of javascript for the "child page". Note however that often that is prevented by the browser configuration, since it is typically considered as bad behavior of a software. It is typically used for annoying advertisement, which is why most users deactivate such stuff.

Comment: U diddnt understand my point,user is on on page x clicks on image and a new _blank page y opens and page x remains still and after some seconds when user is scrolling page y the parent page x redirects to page z

Comment: I think I understood exactly that from your question. Why do you think otherwise? My comment above still is true, you need to open the child window per javascript (no other way) which may be blocked by the client settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it using Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("image_id).onclick = function() {
            var redirectInCurrent = 'same_old.php';
            var openInNew = "new_tab.php";
            window.open(openInNew);
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = redirectInCurrent;
            }, 5000);
        });
      };
   };
</script>
```

`window.open()` will open the child page in a new tab, while `window.location.href` will redirect the parent page to the url in `redirectInCurrent` after 5000 milliseconds.